# Unable to access file in flask app usnig wsgi running on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, flask, wsgi

Flask app running on AWS wsgi unable to open file.

```
 [wsgi:error] IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'input.txt', referer:<ip-address>
```

Comment: That's not a python or a flask issue, just a file permissions issue on your OS, presumably Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a relative file pathname in your code. Work it out as an absolute path. The current working directory of the process will not be where your code is. See more details of why in:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#application-working-directory